# C++ What is the easiest way to achieve my output goal?

Tags: c++, arrays, format, output

I'm experiencing some formatting issues and not exactly sure how I can get it the way I want it. Instead of having the output displayed as

```
1   The contents of table1 are:
    1     2     3     4
    5     6     7     8
    9    10    11    12
```

I would like it to be displayed as

```
2   The contents of table2 are:
    1     4     7    10
    2     5     8    11
    3     6     9    12
```

The above output was provided by this. However, I am not using this code. I just wanted to share how I got the above output.

```
3   #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    const int COLS = 4;
    const int TBL1_ROWS = 3;
    const int TBL2_ROWS = 4;

    void showArray(const int[][COLS], int);

    int main(){
        int table1[TBL1_ROWS][COLS] = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                                       {5, 6, 7, 8},
                                       {9, 10, 11, 12}};
        int table2[TBL2_ROWS][COLS] = {{10, 20, 30, 40},
                                       {50, 60, 70, 80},
                                       {90, 100, 110, 120},
                                       {130, 140, 150, 160}};

        cout << "The contents of table1 are:\n";
        showArray(table1, TBL1_ROWS);
        cout << "The contents of table2 are:\n";
        showArray(table2, TBL2_ROWS);
        return 0;
    }

        void showArray(const int numbers[][COLS], int rows){
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < COLS; y++)
                cout << setw(4) << numbers[x][y] << " ";
            cout << endl;
    }
```

Additionally, I would also like the text to be aligned a certain way. The previous code is something used in class. I am working on a side project that will display a menu to select makes of cars. I want them to be formatted as stated above with the order going down the first column and continues on the second, third, fourth columns. Also, because they are car names instead of numbers, the lengths of them vary. For instance:

```
4   Abarth
    Acura
    Alfa Romeo
    Aston Martin
    Audi
    Bentley
```

I have these stored in an array which is displayed with a loop statement,

```
5   for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        cout << carMakeList[i] << "\t" << endl;
```

The problem I'm running into with these names, is that if I try creating space between the columns using `"\t\t"test`, it will not line up properly. The tab is simply moving from the end of the word, instead of going to the next "tab location". It'd look like this:

```
6   Abarth          test
    Acura           test
    Alfa Romeo          test
    Aston Martin        test
    Audi            test
    Bentley             test
```

Here is the code what I've got so far for my separate thing.

```
7   #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    void showMenu(string[], const int);
    void verifyInput();

    int main(){
        int index = 0;
        const int carNum = 65;
        string carMakeList[carNum];
        ifstream carMakeInput;
        carMakeInput.open("carmakes.txt");
        if(!carMakeInput)
            cout << "Unable to open list of cars.";
        else
            while(getline(carMakeInput, carMakeList[index]))
                index++;
        showMenu(carMakeList, carNum);
    }
    void showMenu(string carMakeList[], const int carNum){
        cout << fixed << left;
        for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
            cout << carMakeList[i] << "\ttest" << endl;
        for(int i = 22; i < 44; i++)
            cout << carMakeList[i] << "\ttest" << endl;
    }
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
8   Abarth              BMW             Daihatsu        Ford
    Acura               Buick           Datsun          Genesis
    Alfa Romeo          Cadillac        Dodge           Geo
    Aston Martin        Chevrolet       Eagle           GMC
    Audi                Chrysler        Ferrari         Honda
    Bentley             Daewoo          FIAT            Hyundai
```

I want to create a menu driven application where a user can select a vehicle by make, year, model, then various information is displayed. I am taking SQL in the second half of this semester, so I had planned on creating a DB after I learn how, but I just wanted to work on the menu for now.

How can I get the output displayed like #2 and formatted like #8 with an array?

Comment: Tip: Consider using `std::vector<string>` as your primary conveyance, not `new[]` or C-style arrays.

Comment: Are you really asking "How do I present a list going from top to bottom, left to right?" If so, do the math on how many each column has by dividing the length by the row count, and then iterate with offsets. A loop inside a loop can easily do this. Hint: Doing this is like going from left to right, top to bottom, except "flipped", meaning you reverse your row/column index calculations.

Comment: @tadman Ah, yes. The Gaddis book was fairly brief on vectors, but I do remember it said vectors are superior to arrays. I'll look into it further. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In C++ `std::vector` is your best friend, so learning about [how it works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and how iterators on them work will save you a *ton* of hassle. The [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in particular is such a delight to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the table to reflect the new arrangement

```
int table1[TBL1_ROWS][COLS] = {{1, 2, 3},
                               {4, 5, 6},
                               {7, 8, 9},
                               {10, 11, 12}};
```

If you want the table to go top to bottom first before left to right first, what you can do is switch up the variables.
Make the variable on the inside loop (y) iterate through columns instead of rows.

```
for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            cout << setw(4) << numbers[y][x] << " ";
        cout << endl;
```